# CreateJS Flash Buttons as links

Tags: html, flash, createjs

I've successfully converted a Flash file to HTML using CreateJS but I am having no joy making a symbol a link.

The buttons work perfectly in the flash movie but when converted to JS/HTML5 it seems to fail. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toolkit for CreateJS does not convert ActionScript-  you will have to either add a frame script

```
/* JS
this.onClick = function() {
    window.location = "http://google.com";
}
*/
```

Or find the symbol in your JavaScript and add the listener there.

```
// The "symbolName" is an instance on the stage in Flash.
exportRoot.symbolName.onClick = function() {
    window.location = "http://google.com";
}
```

You can also create library items yourself and add the listener.

```
var symbol = new lib.MySybmol();
stage.addChild(symbol);
symbol.onClick = function() {
    // etc.
}
```

Hope that helps.

**UPDATE:**
The examples in this answer are out of date. The `onClick` handlers have been deprecated for some time, and need to be replaced with the EventDispatcher `addEventListener()`, or the shortcut `on()` methods:

```
symbol.on("click", function() {
    // etc.
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot will give this a whirl, will let you know how I get on

Answer (score 2):

This is working:

```
// The "instance" is an instance on the stage in Flash
this.instance.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    window.location = "http://google.com";
})
```

I tested it on a Flash Canvas with just one frame and one button

Comment: Yes, the `onClick` methods have been deprecated and removed for some time now. I added an addendum to my answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

i added your code just before the script ending  . And my image has default bitmap instance for one image . but it does not redirect to google

```
exportRoot.instance.onClick = function() {
    window.location = "http://google.com";
```

here is the link : http://canvas.byethost11.com/check/check.html